# Почему в адресе boolean параметр показывается дважды?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

> Это перевод вопроса [Why does query string parameter get included
>   twice - asp.net boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028020/5752652)

У меня есть страница со следующим кодом:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IncludeArchive)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncludeArchive)
    </div>
```

Класс модели:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string TestNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeArchive { get; set; } 
}

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchModel search)
    {
        var test= db.Test.AsQueryable();

        if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0) {
            if (!search.IncludeArchive) test = test.Where(x => x.Status == "Active");
        } else {
            test= test.Where(x => x.Status == "Active");
        }

        ViewBag.testList = test.ToList();
```

Когда я открываю страницу и затем выбираю чекбокс IncludeArchive строка адреса меняется на следующую:

```
http://localhost:64005/test/?FirstName=&LastName=&TestNumber=&IncludeArchive=true&IncludeArchive=false
```

Объясните, почему в url переменная IncludeArchive включается дважды?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028020/5752652

Answer (score 1):

Это не баг, это способ которым MVC фреймворк работает с чекбоксами.

Если вы обратите внимание на сгенерированную HTML-разметку вы увидите, что каждый чекбокс рендерится как html имеющий скрытое поле со значением равным false.

Это гарантирует, что при отправке формы будет передано значение false в случае если пользователь не отметит чекбокс.

Действительно, попробуйте провести следующий эксперимент. Поместите на форму такой чекбокс `<input type="checkbox" name="MyTestCheckboxValue"></input>` и посмотрите, какое значение уходит на сервер в случае, если чекбокс не отмечен.
Вы увидите, что на сервер значение чекбокса не передаётся вообще.

Подобный трюк применяется также в Ruby on Rails и MonoRail.

См. также следующие вопросы:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860940/asp-net-mvcwhy-does-the-checkboxfor-render-an-additional-input-tag-and-how-can